# Creating expensive objects in java

Tags: java, performance, object, constructor

I want to create an object called A with the following properties.

```
public  class A {

    private Object data;

    public A(Object data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

}
```

How do I set up this object so that if two instances have the same value for data, then they refer to the same exact instance? I am creating a very expensive object and do not want duplicates.

Comment: Can you identify something about the object that uniquely identifies it? If so, you can store the objects in a map and first check for the specific instance.

Comment: @Keith the data object uniquely defines the instance.

Comment: How many of these objects do you need?

Comment: Note that putting objects in a plain map-based "pool" means they will never be garbage collected. Is it OK for you that all instances of A will remain in memory forever (for the lifetime of the JVM)?

Comment: Do you want a pool of `A` or a pool of the data? If you already have a reference to the `data` object, who cares about the `A`, it's tiny. Just create every `A` with the same `data`. It's the reference that is copied, not the object.

Comment: I want a poll of A. The actual class I am planning to create will have additional methods besides data.

Comment: Methods are not expensive. Memory and lengthy initializations are expensive.

Comment: @Halbort Is the number of possibilities for `data` unlimited, or is there a fixed set of values? If it's the latter you can just use an `enum` and the instance control is done for you.

Comment: The method is recursive and creates other instances of the A class which recursively call said method.

Comment: @PaulBoddington the number of possibilities is unfortunately unlimited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `Object data` is a composite of more granular pieces, you can couple 
the [Flyweight pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyweight_pattern) with a factory. @Janos already described the Factory and caching mechanism, so here's a brief tutorial on how to use them together:

[Flyweight Pattern in Java Tutorial](http://www.journaldev.com/1562/flyweight-pattern-in-java-example-tutorial) (please read the article in full)

> Flyweight design pattern is used when we need to create a lot of
>   Objects of a class. Since every object consumes memory space that can
>   be crucial for low memory devices, such as mobile devices or embedded
>   systems, flyweight design pattern can be applied to reduce the load on
>   memory by sharing objects.
>
> - The number of Objects to be created by application should be huge.
> - The object creation is heavy on memory and it can be time consuming too.
> - The object properties can be divided into intrinsic and extrinsic properties, extrinsic properties of an Object should be
>     defined by    the client program.
>
> ... The flyweight factory will be used by client programs to instantiate the Object, so we need to keep a map of Objects in the factory that should not be accessible by client application. Whenever client program makes a call to get an instance of Object, it should be returned from the HashMap, if not found then create a new Object and put in the Map and then return it. We need to make sure that all the intrinsic properties are considered while creating the Object.

Answer (score 3):

What you want is called *instance control*: you want to create instances in a controlled manner.

You can achieve this using the factory pattern. Have a factory that keeps a cache of the unique values, mapped to the expensive objects. Disable object creation with any other means, except the factory. When an instance is requested from the factory, check if it's in the cache, if yes then return it. Otherwise, create a new object, put it in the cache, and return it. This is the general idea.

Comment: Yes that it was I was asking about. What is the most idiomatic way of accomplishing it.

Comment: Factory is a very common pattern. You should be able to find a decent implementation easily, for example on wikipedia